# Tastypie migration error

Tags: python, tastypie

I'm trying to install tastypie for Django. I also have South installed. But when I migrate I get some weird type error.

```
./manage.py migrate tastypie
Running migrations for tastypie:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_add_apikey_index.
 > tastypie:0001_initial
TypeError: type() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

I looked into the migration 0002 and type isn't even being called!

Comment: Which version of `tastypie` you're using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug in the latest version (`0.10.0`). A bug report has been submitted. https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/1005.

You can fix it by installing a previous version:

`pip install django-tastypie==0.9.16`

Comment: thanks! I ended up "solving it" by disabling South and running syncdb.

Comment: @Mark in that case you could also use `python manage.py syncdb --all`. Make sure that you first migrated all your other apps :)

Comment: had the same problem with 0.11.0. reverting to 0.9.16 fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (in the 0.11.0 version) and I solved it removing 'tastypie' from INSTALLED_APPS (settings.py).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 0.11.0.

A quick dirty fix is to remove:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

from the migration files.